# Derivative of an integral on a level set

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider a mapping $\xi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $D\xi \, D\xi^T>\delta\, I_k$. Here $D\xi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ is the Jacobian.

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{d}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $A:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
A(z)=\int_{\xi^{-1}(z)} f(x)\,dx.
\end{equation}

Question: Under the assumptions

$\bullet \  \xi\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^k)$ with uniformly bounded derivatives (not the function itself)

$\bullet \  f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^{d};\mathbb{R})$ with uniformly bounded derivatives (not the function itself)

Show that

(1) $A$ is $C^1(\mathbb{R}^k;\mathbb{R})$

(2) If (1) is not true, whats the minimum requirements on $f,\xi$ for (1) to hold.

Notation: Here $C^2$ $(C^1)$ means twice (once) continuously differentiable.

Possible approach: Lets start with trying to show that $A$ is continuous. If we can show that
\begin{equation}
\nabla A(z)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{A(z+h \,z')-A(z)}{h}\leq C,
\end{equation}
then we should be done. Here $h\in \mathbb{R}$ and $z,z'\in \mathbb{R}^k$. Therefore we need to parametrize the level set $\xi^{-1}(z+h\,z')$ in terms of $\xi^{-1}(z)$. From here on I do not know how to proceed. I would expect a parametrisation of these level sets, and then using change of variables and Taylor expansion try to work out the difference above. But I do not know of any details or how to make this intuition of a parametrisation rigorous.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I don't understand the notation in your integral. $f$ is a function defined on $\mathbb R^{d-k}$, but you seem to want to integrate it over $\xi^{-1}(z)$, which is a smooth $(d-k)$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: I apologise for that.  I have changed it to $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Well, now at least it makes sense to restrict $f$ to the manifold $\xi^{-1}(z)\subset\mathbb R^d$. However, now I don't know what you mean by $dx$. This usually refers to the Euclidean volume form on some Euclidean space (for example, on $\mathbb R^d$ it would be $dx = dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^d$). But that does not give a volume form on $\xi^{-1}(z)$. Maybe you need to replace $dx$ by the volume form of the induced Riemannian metric on the submanifold $\xi^{-1}(z)$?

Comment: Well the precise thing would be a $d-k$ dimensional Hausdorff measure. I am sorry, I do not understand volume forms very well. So instead of writing the Hausdorff measure I just went for a $d-k$ dimensional volume measure which off course is not the same thing.

Comment: OK, $(d-k)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is the same as the volume form for the induced Riemannian metric, so at least the integral makes sense. But you're going to have to add some more conditions to ensure that $A$ is a well-defined function. For example, you'll need either for the level sets of $\xi$ to be compact or for $f$ to have compact support. If $\xi\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is given by $\xi(x,y) = x$ and $f(x,y)\equiv 1$, then your conditions are satisfied for any $\delta < 1$, but the integral is infinite for every $z$.

Comment: @JackLee Thank you for these detailed observations. Well $\xi$ does not have compact level sets, however does it help if  it is apriori given that function $A$ is Lipschitz. This would imply that $A$ has linear growth at infinity and differentiable almost everywhere. I am hoping not too go into the details of $f$ since the expressions are nasty.

Comment: @JackLee  Assuming, $f$ is compactly supported as you mentioned. How would one go about proving continuity then?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of suggestions.

The rank theorem (also called the [constant rank theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Constant_rank_theorem)) says that in a neighborhood of each point of $\mathbb R^d$, you can choose smooth coordinates $(u^1,\dots,u^d)$ for $\mathbb R^d$ and $(v^1,\dots,v^k)$ for $\mathbb R^k$ in which $\xi$ has the form $\xi(u^1,\dots,u^d) = (u^1,\dots,u^k)$. By means of a partition of unity, you can write $f$ as a finite sum of smooth functions, each of which is supported in one such neighborhood. Now you've reduced it to the case in which $\xi$ is a linear projection onto the first $k$ coordinates, which should be a lot easier to handle. (One small thing to be careful of: the Hausdorff measure won't be the usual Euclidean measure in these coordinates, but it'll be a smooth function times the Euclidean measure.)